# detect rotated faces microsoft cognitive services

Tags: javascript, face-detection, azure-cognitive-services

I'm currently using Microsoft Cognitive Services to detect and verify faces.
Ive seen that faces are detected ONLY IF the face is turned in the following direction.

[image]

I currently have an Html page that allow to load an image into a canvas, and a button to make a request to Microsoft api.

Now, I have thought a solution but i think that it's not the best for sure.
My idea was to send image (in the worst case 3 times) until the api returns me the id of the face detected (which means the image is rotated correctly), but it's a little bit complex.

So, my question is, how can I automatically rotate the image in the right direction client side?

Sorry for my bad english and thank you in advance for answers.

Answer (score 0):

If the image contains rotation information in exif, the Face API will rotate it automatically. So do you get any specific error?